# Amplify auto fill owner in key

Tags: typescript, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm using AWS Amplify API (as I understand, this is AWS AppSync and Amplify DataStore) with TypeScript.

I've created a graphql type

```
type PrivateNote
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "owner" }])
  @key(fields: ["owner", "id"]) {
  owner: String!
  id: ID!
  content: String!
}
```

Note the `@auth` which specifies `ownerField: "owner"` and the `@key` including `owner`.

The goal of that type is that only creators ("owner") can view/update/delete their data and that the generated DynamoDB's primary key is `["owner", "id"]`.

Using the type as noted above I can successfully generate the code using

```sh
# for backend code
amplify api gql-compile
# for frontend code
amplify codegen model --nodownload
```

The problem is that now I have to explicitly set the owner when creating instances of `PrivateNote` like

```js
const n = new PrivateNote({ 
   content: "my content", 
   owner: "the-owner-id" 
});
```

If I don't set the `owner`, the TypeScript compiler complains and there is also a runtime error saying

> Property 'owner' is missing in type ...

Before setting the `@key` in the graphql schema (and hence also omitting it in the field list of `PrivateNote`) I didn't have to set `owner`, it was done automatically behind the scenes.

So how can I add the owner to a `@key` and still have it auto-filled? And what needs to be changed to have the TypeScript typings generated accordingly?